# How did they find the B matrix for this question?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]

I'm not sure how they found the B matrix for this problem. I have no idea what they did since I keep getting 2,0,0 for the first column and that's already wrong.

Comment: How did you get $(2,0,0)$ for the first column? $L(1)=1+0=1=1(1) + 0t + 0t^2=(1,0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

To find the columns of the matrix it suffices to compute the images by $L$ of the vectors in the basis; the columns are then given by the coordinates of these images.

1. $L(1)=1+0=1\cdot 1+ 0\cdot t+0\cdot (1+t^2)$
2. $L(t)=t+1=1\cdot 1+ 1\cdot t+0\cdot (1+t^2)$
3. $L(1+t^2)=1+t^2+2t=0\cdot 1+ 2\cdot t+1\cdot (1+t^2)$

Now putting these coordinates in columns yields
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 &1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to compute the matrix with respect to the standard basis $\mathfrak{S}=\{1,t,t^2\}$, because
$$
L(1)=1,\quad L(t)=t+1,\quad L(t^2)=t^2+2t
$$
so the matrix is
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The change of basis matrix is
$$
S=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so the matrix you're looking for is
$$
B=SAS^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

<sub>It's a curious fact that the matrices with respect to the bases $\mathfrak{S}$ and $\mathfrak{A}$ are the same.</sub>